# usb_bulk_msg is not able to block

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Scenario : I am trying to read packets getting routed to USB Bulk In Endpoint 4 using `usb_bulk_msg`. My code looks like :

```
static ssize_t bky_read(struct file *f, char __user *buf, size_t cnt, loff_t *off)
{
int retval;
int read_cnt;

/* Read the data from the bulk endpoint */
retval = usb_bulk_msg(device, bky_dev.in, bky_dev.bulk_in_buffer, MAX_PKT_SIZE, &read_cnt,5000);
if (retval)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "Bulk message returned %d\n", retval);
    return retval;
}
if (copy_to_user(buf, bky_dev.bulk_in_buffer, MIN(cnt, read_cnt)))
{
    return -EFAULT;
}

    return MIN(cnt, read_cnt);
}
```

Where `bky_dev.in = usb_rcvbulkpipe (device, in->desc.bEndpointAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_NUMBER_MASK);`
This is done in `probe` call.
I printed the value of `in->desc.bEndpointAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_NUMBER_MASK` and I got `0x4`which is correct. Now when I make a read call from the user-space application, I am able to call `bky_read` but the `usb_bulk_msg` doesnot block for 5 seconds if the data is not available on EP4.

Query: Why the `usb_block_msg` is not able to block for the specified amount of seconds(in my case its 5 seconds).

PS: The `dmesg` prints `Bulk message returned -71` every time I call `read`.

Comment: `-71` is `-EPROTO`; see the [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/usb/error-codes.txt).

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting hardware and the documentation is a befitting testimony to that. Thanks once again.

Comment: The problem has been resolved :)